# Vue3 Composition API - list imported components

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm writing an app in which some content is displayed in dynamic components (`<component :is="...">`). First I want to validate the data so that I only attempt to create the element if the `is` tag will receive the name of an imported component.

In Options API this could be done by finding the name among the keys of `this.$options.components`. What is the equivalent of this in Composition API?

Answer (score 0):

You may :is componends as imported object instead of names

```
<template>
 <div>
  <component v-if="allowed.includes(comp)" :is="comp">
 </div>
</template>
<script>
 import CompA from './A.vue'
 import CompB from './B.vue'
 import CompC from './C.vue'
 let allowed = [CompA, CompB, CompC]
 let comp = /* whatever */ 0;
</script>
```

Comment: True, but that's less elegant and less simple to maintain than an "internal" solution

Comment: Well, but if you provide a component as a Component rather as a name you don't really have to check it *at all*

Comment: I understand, but my question is not about how to refer to a component, rather how to generate a dynamic list of all imported components. I may have 27 different components imported, and for the sake of maintenance I don't want to update both the import list and the manually created array every time one is added or deleted.

Comment: @terminus.technicus do you need that in dev or in prod? Is listing the whole setupScope fine?

Comment: prod. The point would be that the dynamic list of components (locally registered in the parent component) be the basis of validation of the incoming data. So the global component list is not a solution, if you mean that